Convert CSV file into JSON using Qt C++
I have a CSV file containing some variant names and some values in front of them. I am trying to convert it into separated neat json files ( for each column of the CSV I want to create a separate json file).

There are a few conditions:

Rows 0 to 3 are to be ignored (marked in yellow). From row = 4 I want to start collecting the data.

On the 4th row, there is a certain name for each column. The name of the json file for each of these columns should be exactly this name.

Column 1 and 2 are also to be ignored (marked in yellow). I don't want to collect their data.

There are multiple occurrences in the 0-th column. So it should be handled in a way that all multiple identical names are collected with their values, and not only once.


So for example the first json file should be called RA2146905101  00001D72 (row = 4, col = 3), and then I want all the names in col 0 (SPS Rollo, Auftrag A... etc) with their corresponding values in that column (currently col 3) written in the json as keys and values.
The problem: My code collects the values but they seem to be either overwritten or constantly taken from col = 3, because for example in the json file called RA2146905101  00001D72 the value for Rollo einlegen-Macchiatobeige is 0, and in the next column RA2146905101  00008W31 this value is 1, but both json files of both columns write 0 as value, which is incorrect. How can I fix this problem? I'd really appreciate any help, I'm currently so stressed :]
Here's my code:
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // modify path to .csv
    QString basePath = "C:/Users/melika.javadi/Desktop/csv";
    QString csvPath = basePath + "/varineum.csv";

    // start
    parseCSV(csvPath, basePath);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::parseCSV(const QString& readPath, const QString& writePath)
{
    QFile file(readPath);

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        qWarning() << "Unable to open file" << readPath;
        return;
    }

    QTextStream in(&file);
    QStringList columnNames;
    QList<QJsonObject> jsonObjects;

    int rowCounter = 0;

    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        QStringList columns = line.split(";", Qt::KeepEmptyParts);

        // Skip the first 4 rows
        if (rowCounter < 4) {
            rowCounter++;
            continue;
        }

        // Handle the 4th row for column names starting from the 3rd column
        if (rowCounter == 4) {
            for (int i = 2; i < columns.size(); ++i) {
                columnNames.append(columns[i].trimmed());
                jsonObjects.append(QJsonObject());  // Prepare empty JSON objects for each column
            }
        }
        // Process rows that contain data
        else {
            QString itemName = columns[0].trimmed();  // First column is item name

            for (int i = 3; i < columns.size(); ++i) {  // Iterate over the data columns
                QString occurrence = columns[i].trimmed();

                // Access the correct JSON object for the current column
                QJsonObject &jsonObject = jsonObjects[i - 3];

                // Insert the occurrence into the JSON object for the current column
                jsonObject[itemName] = occurrence;
            }
        }

        rowCounter++;
    }
    file.close();

    // Write each JSON object into separate files
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); ++i) {
        QString jsonFileName = writePath + "/" + columnNames[i] + ".json";
        QFile jsonFile(jsonFileName);

        if (!jsonFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            qDebug() << "Unable to open file for writing:" << jsonFileName;
            continue;
        }

        // Create JSON document
        QJsonDocument doc(jsonObjects[i]);

        // Write JSON data to file
        jsonFile.write(doc.toJson());
        jsonFile.close();
    }
}

And here is the csv:
;<HEADER>;;;2024-09-23T13:54:37;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Variante;;;RA2146905101  00001D72;RA2146905101  00008W31;RA2146905101  00009K94;RA2146906700  00001D72;RA2146906700  00008W31;RA2146906700  00009K94;RA2146907400  00001D72;RA2146907400  00008W31;RA2146907400  00009K94;RA2146907600  00001D72;RA2146907600  00008W31;RA2146907600  00009K94;RA2146907800  00001D72;RA2146907800  00008W31;RA2146907800  00009K94;RA2146907900  00001D72;RA2146907900  00008W31;RA2146907900  00009K94;RA2146908000  00001D72;RA2146908000  00008W31;RA2146908000  00009K94;RA2146908300  00001D72;RA2146908300  00008W31;RA2146908300  00009K94;RA2146908400  00001D72;RA2146908400  00008W31;RA2146908400  00009K94;RA2146908600  00001D72;RA2146908600  00008W31;RA2146908600  00009K94;RA2146908700  00001D72;RA2146908700  00008W31;RA2146908700  00009K94;RA2146908800  00001D72;RA2146908800  00008W31;RA2146908800  00009K94
Bemerkungen;;;;Macchiatobeige Rollo Sound USA;Schwarz Rollo Sound USA;Digitalwei� Serie ECE;Macchiatobeige Serie ECE;Schwarz Serie ECE;Digitalwei� Serie Sound ECE;Macchiatobeige Serie Sound ECE;Schwarz Serie Sound ECE;Digitalwei� Serie USA;Macchiatobeige Serie USA;Schwarz Serie USA;Digitalwei� Serie Privacy Austr.;Macchiatobeige Serie Privacy Austr.;Schwarz Serie Privacy Austr.;Digitalwei� Serie Sound USA;Macchiatobeige Serie Sound USA;Schwarz Serie Sound USA;Digitalwei� Serie Sound Privacy Austr.;Macchiatobeige Serie Sound Privacy Austr.;Schwarz Serie Sound Privacy Austr.;Digitalwei� Rollo ECE;Macchiatobeige Rollo ECE;Schwarz Rollo ECE;Digitalwei� Rollo Sound ECE;Macchiatobeige Rollo Sound ECE;Schwarz Rollo Sound ECE;Digitalwei� Serie Privacy;Macchiatobeige Serie Privacy;Schwarz Serie Privacy;Digitalwei� Serie Sound Privacy;Macchiatobeige Serie Sound Privacy;Schwarz Serie Sound Privacy;Digitalwei� Rollo USA;Macchiatobeige Rollo USA;Schwarz Rollo USA
;</HEADER>;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Bemerkungen;Position;;RA2146905101  00001D72;RA2146905101  00008W31;RA2146905101  00009K94;RA2146906700  00001D72;RA2146906700  00008W31;RA2146906700  00009K94;RA2146907400  00001D72;RA2146907400  00008W31;RA2146907400  00009K94;RA2146907600  00001D72;RA2146907600  00008W31;RA2146907600  00009K94;RA2146907800  00001D72;RA2146907800  00008W31;RA2146907800  00009K94;RA2146907900  00001D72;RA2146907900  00008W31;RA2146907900  00009K94;RA2146908000  00001D72;RA2146908000  00008W31;RA2146908000  00009K94;RA2146908300  00001D72;RA2146908300  00008W31;RA2146908300  00009K94;RA2146908400  00001D72;RA2146908400  00008W31;RA2146908400  00009K94;RA2146908600  00001D72;RA2146908600  00008W31;RA2146908600  00009K94;RA2146908700  00001D72;RA2146908700  00008W31;RA2146908700  00009K94;RA2146908800  00001D72;RA2146908800  00008W31;RA2146908800  00009K94
SPS Rollo;1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
Auftrag A_Sachnummer und Produktionsnummer scannen;2;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
A-Sachnummer scannen;  2.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Produktionsnummer scannen;  2.2;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Fertigungsablauf;3;;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Digitalwei� Serie mit Sound;  3.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0
Digitalwei� Serie ohne Sound;  3.2;;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Macchiatobeige Serie mit Sound;  3.3;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0
Macchiatobeige Serie ohne Sound;  3.4;;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Schwarz Heller ;4;;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0
Schwarz Serie mit Sound;  4.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0
Schwarz Serie ohne Sound;  4.2;;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0
Rollo einlegen-anschlie�en-ausfahren;5;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
Rollo einlegen-Schwarz;  5.1;;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1
Rollo einlegen-Macchiatobeige;  5.2;;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0
Rollo einlegen-Digitalwei�;  5.3;;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0
Rollo Stecker Heller;6;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
Stecker Rollo einstecken;  6.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
Rollo Hutablage einlegen;7;;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0
Digitalwei� Rollo mit Sound;  7.1;;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Digitalwei� Rollo ohne Sound;  7.2;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0
Macchiatobeige Rollo mit Sound;  7.3;;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Macchiatobeige Rollo ohne Sound;  7.4;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0
 Schwarz Heller;8;;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1
Schwarz Rollo mit Sound;  8.1;;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Schwarz Rollo ohne Sound;  8.2;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1
Hutablage einlegen und Spanner bet�tigen;9;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Schwarz Rollo mit Sound;  9.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Schwarz Rollo ohne Sound;  9.2;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Digitalwei� Rollo mit Sound;  9.3;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Digitalwei� Rollo ohne Sound;  9.4;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Macchiatobeige Rollo mit Sound;  9.5;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Macchiatobeige Rollo ohne Sound;  9.6;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Hutablage einlegen - Rollo;  9.7;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Hutablage einlegen - Serie;  9.8;;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0
SPS Handshake Rollo;10;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
;  10.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Farbkontrolle;11;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Schwarz 00009K94;  11.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Macchiatobeige 00008W31;  11.2;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Digitalwei� 00001D72;  11.3;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Verschrauben 4;12;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
Rollo verschrauben (4-Schrauben);  12.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
SPS Handshake Zycl 1 (4 Schrauben);13;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
;  13.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1
Kisi-Abdeckung (ohne Druckbild) montieren, 3 St�ck;14;;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Schwarz;  14.1;;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1
Kisi-Abdeckung (ohne Druckbild) montieren, 3 St�ck;15;;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;1;1;0;1;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Macchiatobeige;  15.1;;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Digitalwei�;  15.2;;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0
Kisi-Abdeckung (mit Druckbild) ECE montieren, 2 St�ck;16;;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Schwarz;  16.1;;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Macchiatobeige;  16.2;;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Digitalwei�;  16.3;;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0
Blende Mitte montieren, 1 St�ck;17;;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Schwarz;  17.1;;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0
Blende Mitte montieren, 1 St�ck;18;;0;0;0;1;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Macchiatobeige;  18.1;;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0
Einclipsen und �berpr�fen-Digitalwei�;  18.2;;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0
Snaplock eindr�cken, 3 St�ck Rechts und 3 St�ck Links;19;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
Eindr�cken Schwarz;  19.1;;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0
Eindr�cken Macchiatobeige;  19.2;;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0
Eindr�cken Digitalwei�;  19.3;;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0
Lautsprecher einsetzen;20;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
LSP Montage;  20.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
Lautsprecherabdeckung verbauen;21;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
Lautsprecherabdeckung-Schwarz;  21.1;;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0
Lautsprecherabdeckung-Macchiatobeige;  21.2;;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0
Lautsprecherabdeckung-Digitalwei�;  21.3;;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0
Bremsleuchte auf Variante pr�fen;22;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Rotes Glas;  22.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
Wei�es Glas;  22.2;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0
Klammerpr�fung Leuchte;  22.3;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
OKE anbringen, 2 St�ck;23;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Einklipsen;  23.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
SPS ohne Lautsprecher 1;24;;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1
Aufnahme drehen;25;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Drehen;  25.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Halter vorhanden?;  25.2;;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0
Rastnasen verrasten;26;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Rastnasen auf Verrastung pr�fen;  26.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Rollo verschrauben (7 Schrauben);27;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
Rollo verschrauben;  27.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
SPS Handshake Zycl 2 (7Schrauben);28;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
handshake IO=1 von SPS;  28.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
SPS ohne Lautsprecher 2;29;;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1
handshake IO=1 von SPS;  29.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
SPS mit Lautsprecher;30;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
handshake IO=1 von SPS;  30.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Lautsprecherkabel zur Pr�fung einstecken;31;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
Stecker einstecken;  31.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
Pr�ftaster dr�cken;  31.2;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
Lautsprecherkabel nach Verlegelinie befestigen, 9x Klebestreifen-�berl�nge 130 mm;32;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
Verlegeplan;  32.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0
�berl�nge Kabel Bremsleuchte (120 mm) mit Tesa-Krepp fixieren;33;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Befestigung Bremsleuchte kontrollieren;  33.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Rollokabel befestigen, 5x Klebestreifen;34;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
kleben;  34.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
SPS Handshake Lautsprecher mit & ohne;35;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Handshake SPS IO =1 lesen ;  35.1;;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1
SPS Handshake IO Lautsprecher mit & ohne;36;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Handshake SPS IO = 0 lesen;  36.1;;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1
Bremsleuchtekabel anschlie�en;37;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Bremsleuchtenkabel anschlie�en-Pr�fung abwarten und wieder abstecken;  37.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Clip pr�fen;  37.2;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Anschlu�kabel Bremsleuchte befestigen, 4x Klebestreifen;38;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
vorgeben und �berpr�fen;  38.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
SPS Handshake Bremsleuchte;39;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
;  39.1;;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Alle Stecker vor Entnahme ziehen;40;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
Stecker Rollo ziehen;  40.1;;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1
OKE pr�fen;41;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
OKE pr�fen;  41.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Aufnahme drehen und Spanner durch Ende_Auftrag l�sen;42;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Ende und neuer Auftrag;  42.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
SPS Handshake Ende;43;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
SPS Handshake Ende;  43.1;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
Bauteil entnehmen;44;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
Bauteil entnehmen;  44.1;;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;#WERT!;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;



You are making your life to complicated. Do not mix code of JSon and CVS together. Do two seperate steps. In first read data from CSV to some data structure (some QVector<QVector<QString> or QMap<QVector<QString>> or something specyfic to your business logic.. When you done doing this create code which will convert this data into JSon objects which yo will write to file.

Offtopic: looks like to handle encoding properly you should set some setEncoding or setLocale on QTextStream.

@MarekR Could you be more specific how to populate the containers then please?

@Melika Don't try to skip steps unless you're extremely aware of what you want to do. Create a concept for a data model that fully represents the data you need to eventually read and write (you have to imagine it, writing it down on paper also helps). After that, decide/implement the data structure, then finally how the source will be unserialized from CSV to that structure, and how that structure will be serialized back to json. Trying to do all that in a single step is not impossible, but extremely hard to achieve, therefore prone to bugs caused by unexpected aspects. Use abstraction.
